# What is a proper way to handle multiple level dependency of third-party libraries in CMake

Tags: cmake, external-project

I am developing a CMake project depending on multiple third-party libraries, and these libraries may further depend on other third-party libraries. The dependencies are all built as static libraries. I use `ExternalProject` to download and compile the dependencies.

```
                  /=> lib4.a
       /=> lib2.a  => lib5.a
lib1.so 
       \=> lib3.a
```

When linking `lib1` against `lib2`, the symbols from `lib4` and `lib5` are missing. My alternative is to manually import `lib4` and `lib5` into `lib1` and link against them. But this will cause all the dependencies to be built twice. When there are many dependencies, manually handling this becomes very hard.

I am thinking if there is a way for `lib2` to create a big library (`lib2-ALL`) that includes everything from `lib2`, `lib4` and `lib5`. So `lib1` only needs to link against `lib2-ALL`. However, I am not sure how to do this properly in CMake.

What is a proper way to manage such multi-level third-party library dependencies?

Comment: If they're all CMake builds, then install everything in dependency order to a common prefix and set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` appropriately for each project. Otherwise, try vcpkg, it's designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Maybe post some CMakeList snippets so that we can better understand what you are trying to do. Are you perhaps working with shared libraries? Because static libraries should be easier to work with.